# Destroying a merge() operator subscription?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

[In this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/) a the `merge` operator is being used to subscribe to both sort and paging events.  The function looks like this:

```
    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.loadLessonsPage())
        )
        .subscribe();
```

Do we need to hold on on to the subscription and call unsubscribe when the component is destroyed?

Comment: https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes!

More expanded answer: You don't have to do it manually!

You can use plenty of `operators` to help you manage the subscription. An even better way to not manage the subscription at all is to let your HTML do it for you using the `AsyncPipe`.

Example:

```
component

this.sortAndPaging = merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.loadLessonsPage())
        )
```

```
html

<div *ngIf="sortAndPaging | async as sortAndPaginaData">
 {{ sortAndPagingData | json }}
</div>
```

This way, Angular's lifecycle management in combination with the `AsyncPipe` will keep track and subscribe/unsubscribe from the subscription itself.

Another powerful solution, as I mentioned earlier, is using `operators` to do it. RxJS comes with plenty of powerful tools like `first()`, `take(x)`, `takeUntil()` and `takeWhile()` that will complete and unsubscribe automatically for you.

`take(10)` will complete and unsubscribe after 10 values have passed through for example.

More specific tips for your situation will require a more expansive question and some examples of what you've tried.

Comment: So is it automatically done somehow?

Comment: This should be a comment, mate :)

Comment: I see this used a lot https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-auto-unsubscribe

Comment: But I thought at a minimum we would need something like that and to implement `OnDestroy`?

Comment: Updated it Mosé as I was still typing :-).

Comment: I would advise using the `takeUntil` approach (if you can't use the `async` pipe), and having a `Subject` which only emits in `ngOnDestroy`. This saves you from having a thousand subscription variables:
`ngOnDestroy() { this.destroy$.next(true); }`

Comment: I also prefer the `takeUntil()` approach, except for the fact that it usually comes with a `Subject`. But other then that, it's a very solid solution yes.

Comment: Let me add, that just doing `this.destroy$.next()` is not enough. You need to complete the Subject too to trigger its teardown logic. `this.destroy$.next(); this.destroy$.complete(); this.destroy$.unsubscribe()` works best in my experience.

Comment: Very cool - Thanks!